# how to display images in gridview from url

Tags: android

Hi when i am trying this code to dipaly images from imageurl in gridview 
it is showing null pointer exception can any one help me:
my code is

```
public class Gridview extends Activity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gridview);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);   
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
   }
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


    private Context mContext;
    private Integer[] mThumbIds;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;     
    }
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(45, 45));
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView
            .setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://tmcrmappsqa.inservices.tatamotors.com/cordys/Images/mobile.png"+position));
    return imageView;
}
protected Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(0);
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You should not be loading images individually from a URL on the UI thread in getView. You should fetch all the images through an AsyncTask and update the GridView in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

Hey check your image download url. why did you appended position to that url? if that you have many images like mobile1, mobile2 and etc then you should append position after mobile and not after url.

And most importantly you cannot do network operations on main UI thread as you are doing now. it may work on GingerBread and Pre-GingerBread devices but not on later GingerBread device.

Just refer this [link](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) and do it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the url, +position will lead to incorrect url:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://tmcrmappsqa.inservices.tatamotors.com/cordys/Images/mobile.png"+position));
```